# Social icons appear on top left of screen when loading

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I have a block of social icons on my website at the top right of the header, when the website is loading you can see the icons appear in the top left, but they move over to their correct position once the site is loaded. It makes the page look rather stupid when this happens even if its only for a second or two. Anyway to make it so that the block of social icons loads in the top right from the get go?

HTML

```
<div id="socialicons">
<a href=""><img src="" alt="RSS" /></a>
<a href=""><img src="" alt="Tumblrr" /></a>
<a href=""><img src="" alt="Pinterest" /></a>
<a href=""><img src="" alt="Google+" /></a>
<a href=""><img src="" alt="Facebook" /></a>
<a href=""><img src="" alt="Twitter" /></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#socialicons {
    padding-right: 150px;
}

#socialicons img {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 3px;
    display: block;
}
```

Here is an example of what it looks like while in admin mode.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3FMH.jpg
Here is what it looks like while loading.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaPrS.jpg
After it loads, it looks just like the first image.

Comment: Can you share the link or code please? You've made it very hard to address your problem in a specific manner.

Comment: Here you go, I have added the code

Comment: Try setting the `width` for `#socialicons`.

Comment: I dont even know what I should be setting the width to...I am not that great when it comes to HTML and CSS. Do I set the width to be the amount of pixels from the left side of the screen to where I want the icons to start?

Comment: I just set the width to 1100px and it lines up to where I had it with the padding, when the site loads up it still does the same thing. I have images linked up in the main post to give you guys an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML

```
<div id="nav">

   <ul id="nav-items">
         <li>Home</li>
         <li>About</li>
         <li>etc...</li>
   </ul><!-- this ul will hold the menu options -->

   <div id="socialicons">
     <a href=""><img src="" alt="RSS" /></a>
     <a href=""><img src="" alt="Tumblrr" /></a>
     <a href=""><img src="" alt="Pinterest" /></a>
     <a href=""><img src="" alt="Google+" /></a>
     <a href=""><img src="" alt="Facebook" /></a>
     <a href=""><img src="" alt="Twitter" /></a>
   </div><!-- this is your social icons wrapper -->

</div><!-- this div will hold both menu options and socialicons -->
```

CSS

```
#nav{
    width:1024px; /* fixed width */
    margin:auto;  /* this div will be centered */
}

#navitems{
    float:left; /* this block contains the menu and it will float to the left */
}

#navitems li{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:2px; /* depending on how much space do you want between items */
    text-align: center; /* the text will be centered inside each list element. */
}

#socialicons{
    float:right; /* this block will float right */
}
#socialicons img {
    display:inline-block; /* use it instead "float:right" */
    padding-top: 3px;
    display: block;
}
```